# Trying to get procedure name from SQL Server Profiler, 'sp_reset_connection' shows instead

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-profiler

I have C# app which executes database tored procedures. I can get the result from these procedures successfully, but SQL Server Profiler shows 'sp_reset_connection' instead of procedures names. I set event filter to 'Stored Procedures' in SQL Server Profiler. In columns I have 'ObjectName' and 'TextData', both show 'sp_reset_connection' when I execute stored procedures from my app.

C# code (variant code equals smth like "exec dbo.sp_name_1"):

```
public string ExecSpReturnTime(string connectionString, string code)
    {
        long execTime = 0;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.StatisticsEnabled = true;
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(code, connection))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            var stats = connection.RetrieveStatistics();
            execTime = (long)stats["ExecutionTime"];
        }
        return execTime.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: please provide your code which connects with database.

Comment: `sp_reset_connection` is a dummy stored proc executed to make connection pooling work. You can safely ignore calls to it. Or are you saying that you're *only* seeing calls to it? If the latter, it means your need to change what you're capturing in the profiler.

Comment: Yes, it is the only thing i see. I'll try to find appropriate filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added filter in SQL Profiler 'Stored Procedures -> SP:Complited' and now I can see my procedures. Thanks, Damien_The_Unbeliever!